# Concatenacion de campos SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo 2 campos, `CodPlan` y `Nro`, necesito concatenar los dos en otro campo llamado  `id`, me explico si el `CodPlan` es 11 y el `Nro` es 5, el `Id` debe quedar 115, que seria la concatenacion de ambos campos, pero no he logrado encontrar la manera de hacerlo desde SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE TblPlaneacion(
CodigoPlan int Foreign key References TblPlanAccion,
Nro Int
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez haciendo un campo calculado y con la funcion `CONCAT()`, Podes crear el campo id y simplemente decirle que concatene los datos insertados de los otros dos campos.

```
CREATE TABLE TblPlaneacion(
Id as Concat(CodigoPlan,Nro),
CodigoPlan int Foreign key References TblPlanAccion,
Nro Int)
```

Igual aca te dejo un link donde explican como usar la Funcion `CONCAT()`
[Funcion CONCAT](https://www.1keydata.com/es/sql/sql-concatenar.php)